# HTTP requests between IONIC 3 and NODE not working

Tags: angular, http, ionic3

I'm trying to connect my Ionic app with my server but I'm heading into an error that I couldn't find a solution.

I already have turned on a CORS plugin on chrome but still it doesn't work. It works on Postman but not here.

I'm using Node as a backend and Ionic as a front.

This is my user.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

getCities(){

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/cities', {
      country: 'Brazil'
    })
    .subscribe(response => {

         console.log('response',response);

  }
}
```

this is my server

```
app.post('/cities',function(req,res){
  var options = { method: 'POST',
  url:  'http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx',
  qs: { WSDL: '' },
  headers: 
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'text/xml',
   },
  body: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">\r\n  <soap12:Body>\r\n    <GetCitiesByCountry xmlns="http://www.webserviceX.NET">\r\n      <CountryName>Brazil</CountryName>\r\n    </GetCitiesByCountry>\r\n  </soap12:Body>\r\n</soap12:Envelope>'
  };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
  res.send(body);
  res.end();
});


});
```

It logs on my server console but not in the client's side. 
This is the error that is returning from client's side.

```
  HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/users", ok: false, …}
  headers : HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: ƒ}
  "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/cities"
  name : "HttpErrorResponse"
  ok : false
  status : 200
  statusText : "OK"
  url : "http://localhost:3000/cities"
```

Does anyone know any solution?
Do you have a better approach to this code? I already tried access-control-allow-origin on the header but nothing.

As I am always learning, I appreciate an explanation if you find a solution.

Thanks!

Comment: The HttpClient expects a response in JSON format as default, not XML. You either change the return format of your backend or adjust the config of the HttpClient

Comment: Nice. Do you know or suggest how should I do that?

Comment: I found out and just added a `responseType:'text'` to the options parameter of the post request in my client. Now, is that the best way? How would I convert it to be able to access the values from the object?

Comment: Either format the XML to JSON or simply return JSON from your backend. I would go for the 2nd